# Showing a default value in a WebGrid when a null is present?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I've got Webgrid sourced to a EF4 entity with navigation properties (basically relationships)

If the webgrid encounters a null for that foreign key it errors out because it's looking for that object, which in this case doesn't exist.

Is it possible to catch when a column item is null and default to a value within the Webgrid helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the follwoing code should serve your purpose if I am correctly relating to your problem. Below Trigger is the navigated entity which we will get by include in linq and we can put a check like below when this entity is null.

```
grid.Column("Job", format: @<text>  @if (@item.Trigger !=null) { <span> Write your default code here .</span> } </text> close text tag here ),
```

Hope that solves your problem.

I noticed after posting 'text' is getting truncated in this forum so put text in < and > between 2 @ as you can see and also close that text tag before the final ).

All the best.